# Display white screen when running c++ on blend for visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried to run this code written in C++,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pch.h>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

in Blend for Visual Studio 2015, after a successful build and running start without debugging the output is just a pop up of white screen without hello world. I'm learning c++ and this was I encountered.

Anyone experience this in visual studio?

Comment: maybe you miss the return statement for int main().

Comment: Just run in it Visual Studio. This has nothing to do with Blend.

Comment: I know now how. I already figured it out.